# How can I filter ManyToManyField items base on user groups?

Tags: django-models, django-admin, django-authentication, manytomanyfield, django-3.2

###### staff.models.py

```
from django.db import models    
from website.models import Website

class Staff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    websites = models.ManyToManyField(Website) # CHOICES = ['Chemical','Mechanical','IT']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can I filter ManyToManyField(websites field) items base on user groups. For example, if user have group1 access, he can only view  `CHOICES = ['Chemical','IT']` and select one of them.

###### website.models

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

MY_CHOICES = ['chemical','mechnical','IT']

class Website(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    webapps = MultiSelectField(choices = MY_CHOICES, blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: For user you used django default user model ??

Comment: Yes, I use default user model.

Comment: please add website model in question

Comment: @Mahammadhusainkadiwala , website models added